# Oauth 2 password grant flow not working in react native with axios

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, axios

I am trying to get token from OAM server using OAuth 2.0 password grant flow in a react native application.But iam getting 401 invalid client id param always.

I've tried on postman and it is working and also i tried with java code it is also working but when iam trying in react native and axios iam always getting the  401 invalid client id param error.

Java code which is working is

public class TestService {

```
private static String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL =
    "http://oauthservice/tokens";
//Redirect URI for Authorization flow
private static String REDIRECT_URI = "redirect_uri=http://ClientWebApp/index.html";
//Client Credentials
private static String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

private static String BASE_64_CREDENTIALS = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET));
//Authorization and Token properties
private static String GRANT_TYPE = "grant_type=password";
private static String STATE = "state=getaccess";
private static String USERNAME = "username=xxxxxxx";
private static String PASSWORD = "password=xxxxxxx";

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String testService() {
    String accessToken = null;

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("###TestService called...: " );
        //Constructs post Data
        String params = GRANT_TYPE + "&" + USERNAME + "&" + PASSWORD;
        byte[] postData = params.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        //Constructs URL and Connection objects, and sets headers
        URL url = new URL(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", BASE_64_CREDENTIALS);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Gets response and reads it
        OutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(postData);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer resp = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            resp.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

        String res = resp.toString();

        System.out.println("res: "+res );      
        //Obtains access token from JSON object
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
        accessToken = obj.getString("access_token");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return accessToken;
}
```

}

React Native code (I have tried many ways but none is working)

1)
axios.post("http://oauthservice/tokens", 
qs.stringify({  grant_type:"password",
          username:"xxxxxx",
          password:"xxxxxxx",
          scope:"xxxxxxxx" }), {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'Authorization': "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        })

```
  .then((response) => {
  alert(response)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     alert(JSON.stringify(error.response))
  })
```

2)

axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'oauthservice/tokens',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': "Basic "+encoded_values,
        }, 
        data:     qs.stringify({
          grant_type:"password",
          username:"xxxxxx",
          password:"xxxxx",
          scope:"xxxxxxxx"
        })
      }
      ) .then((response) => {
        alert(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           alert(JSON.stringify(error.response))
        });

I have tried many third party packages like https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-oauth-client

But they also providing the same error.